# Strategies for walls

Tags: modeling

Not sure why I can't find any info on this.

When trying to model the inside of a house, I find it difficult to figure out how to both have a workflow that allows for both having more advanced features like walls with different thickness, slanted walls, varying height and using bevels. In the attached image, I have tried 2 methods.

I find the upper one a lot easier to work with. I basically model some "lego" bricks, and piece them together. The big drawback is I cannot figure out how to do stuff like bevel the edges. On the image I used the bevel modifier to show the "problem". But even bevelling single edges gives me issues, for example around the windows. Because there are multiple island bordering each other.

The method used in the lower example otoh I find very difficult to use when I have irregular walls (varying thickness, slanted). It requires adding a lot of geometry as well, whenever there's a feature (like a window).

[image]

Most helpful video I've found so far on this is:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cunh57XjRv4

But still. All his example are rather simple.

Can someone explain or point me to a tutorial on how to achieve the kind of simpleness the "upper" method has, but still allowing for stuff like bevels?

Comment: Have you considered enabling the (built-in) add-on "Archipack".  Once added you will have a new menu item in 3d-view "Add" called Archipack, and will also have Arhipack in the  "Create" sidebar tab.  You can create various Floor, Wall, Window, and misc furniture objects that can save loads of effort and time.

Comment: Here is the link for the Arhipack home page:  https://blender-archipack.org/

Comment: Thanks, I do use that for windows and doors. But not walls. Maybe it's just me not understanding it, but I'm not sure how the walls make it a lot better than just extruding parts manually. My main issues are with slanted walls (not shown in example, but when the upper half of a wall is slanted like 45 degrees (like on the top floor of a house)), or when a part of the wall is thinner than the rest, like in the image above where the wall section under the window is thinner (recessing?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found this video from the same guy:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZD8sSX7NtU

It uses booleans to cut out doors and windows. Seems to work for the above. Haven't tried it yet for slanted walls, but here's hoping it will do.
I was reluctant to use booleans first because they seemed so buggy. May not be buggy, just very hard to use whenever something is a little off. In my case, turned out one of my normals was pointing inwards and that was confusing everything.